# Are these white things roots?

Tags: propagation, roots

I have this very unhappy kalanchoe (freedom bells) I was looking to propagate it by getting cuttings fro the stems and then putting putting them in water, but I noticed it was growing these white things from near the top of the stem, are these roots? can I cut of the top of the stem and put it into soil?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are aerial roots. They are indeed a [sign](https://www.succulentsandsunshine.com/aerial-roots-succulents-normal/) of unhappiness... They probably don't get enough water or light.

You can propagate thru [leaf](https://www.doityourself.com/stry/2--ways-to-propagate-a-kalanchoe) cuttings. Usually for succulents, propagation is by putting the cutting directly in (dry-ish) soil, and not in water.

Comment: Ok thank you, this plant has indeed had a rough time, it got too much sun, was was then potted with a spider plant whose roots took up the whole pot, then was over watered and now apparently underwatered. I was wondering if I could use the aerial roots that have already formed to start a new cutting? so just take a part of the stem with aerial roots and pt it into some soil, would that work?

Comment: I think that should also work, in general succulents are easy to propagate by cuttings. Don't make the soil too wet, it can cause rot.

Comment: That will work, but be careful - it's easy to break off the aerial roots when potting up your cutting. Pot the cutting into damp soil, and don't water again till you see some signs of growth - and then never over-water. Succulents can survive long periods of drought, but too much water causes them to rot.